# Using a form to change css stylesheet

Tags: html

I use about a dozen different templates for several different vertical markets that I customize for CLients. I add custom Headers, footers and links and develop a color pallet and font used based on their preferences.

I would like to have a form that updates their own css files after the Client logs in and also offer a upload for their own custom logos, headers footers etc, these could be in html or jpg,png format, to be included in their sites.

Does anyone know of a program or scripts that can do this, or do I need to write it myself.

Thanks

Comment: Which programming language? Platform?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is an abundance of Content Management solutions that would include various flavours of this functionality, but you're looking for it in isolation.  My suspicion is that you're going to have to write it yourself.

Just to clarify: when the user logs in to your application, you want it to draw specific style elements based on preferences set for their account (or for general preferences set against their organisation)?

It sounds like you want to store all this information in a database and have styles inserted into the HTML on page render.  If you want something that would actually create a stylesheet and write it to the filesystem, as I said before, it's likely that you'll have to build the functionality to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing is in the domain of a Content Management System.  So, you have a couple of choices.

1. Try to integrate your work into an existing CMS like drupal, joomla, DotnetNuke, etc (depending on what language you are coding in); or,
2. Build your own.

You can certainly leverage existing components such as a rich text editor (like the one you used to post the question) in combination with writing the files to a DB or straight to the file system.

Either way, you have a fair amount of work ahead of you.

Comment: I was afraid, writing it, was going to be the only real answer.
Since each vertical application reuses the same html and javascript
for different customers, I am trying to lessen my direct involvment.
I now just change the css and some xml files to customize the apps.
I guess using mysql and creating the css when they update the database is the best solution.
There goes another couple of weeks from my Life.

Answer (score 0):

try something with php, [Maybe a script like this?](http://www.easyphpscripts.com/index.php?main_page=EasyPHPEdit&cat=Scripts)